# how to save index of variable in matrix to count the number of occurrences

Tags: r, append

```
    for (i in 1:10){

      z1<-rnorm(1000,0,1)
      z2<-rnorm(1000,0,1)
      z3<-rnorm(1000,0,1)
      z4<-rnorm(1000,0,1)
      z5<-rnorm(1000,0,1)
      z6<-rnorm(1000,0,1)
      z7<-rnorm(1000,0,1)

      X<-cbind(z1,z2,z3,z4,z5,z6)

      Z<-apply(X,2,mean)
       test[i]<-which(Z>0.01, arr.ind=TRUE)

    }
```

I am interested here to save the index of Z under condition in another variable to count at end how many indices were full filling the condition.

For example 
Let first output was
3 4 
second output
6
third
1 2 3 5

now i want to compute that output these 3 outputs how many ones, twos, threes etc were appeared.

Here in all these 3 outputs
1 appeared 1 time
2 appeared 1 time
3 appeared 2 times 
4 appeared 1 time
5 appeared 1 time
6 appeared 1 time.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can either use a matrix with NA's or a list. It doesn't make sense to repeat those loops with two different sequences of `i`'s. You should explain what the goal is.

Comment: sorry, one loop was extra, now it is edited. I am not to much expert in R language. Can u explain with code.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways:

Unvectorized

```
do.one <- function() 
  which(colMeans(replicate(7, rnorm(1000))) > .01)
replicate(10, do.one(), simplify=FALSE)
```

Vectorized

```
do.one <- function() 
  colMeans(replicate(7, rnorm(1000))) > .01
replicate(10, do.one())
```

Comment: Thanks ashkan.
Your code partially fulfills my objective. I need to count the index appeared to be TRUE or FALSE. Thanks it also help me to avoid for loops.
One question is also in my mind regarding learning objective is that how I can use any one of the replicate.
for example If I write Z<-replicate(7,rnorm(1000)), then how I can get z1, z2, z3, etc.
Thanks again

Comment: TRUE / FALSE variables are automatically cast to 1 / 0 respectively when applying numeric operations, so just reduce the values using a sum statement.